# hyper-v computer getting ip from dhcp that on other subnet

Tags: dhcp, subnet

i'v installed windows server 2019 with dhcp server role

i'v created a virtual lan switch 192.168.70.1 / 255.255.255.0

and created dhcp scope: 192.168.9.1 - 192.168.9.10 with subnet 255.255.0.0

**notice that the scope and virual lan arent in the same subnet**

the hyper-v machine getting the dhcp from the virtual lan

she getting ip of 192.168.9.5

how the hyper-v machine get dhcp from 192.168.70.1 that is on class C , and

the hyper-v machine is on class B and they both on different subnet

the hyper-v machine cannot even ping the virtual lan ip but can get dhcp from it ?

please help thanks

Comment: You may want to edit the question so that you're not asking for an opinion, see https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Give the Guest machine an External IP (Hyper-V Switch).  You are on NAT right now

Comment: NAT has internal DHCP and External (Bridged) gets DHCP from the router.

Comment: It would appear the hyper-v VM is connected to the same logical network as the DHCP server. Check your virtual switch configuration again. It’s not clear in your question how things are actually configured.

Comment: This is expected behavior. I’m not sure why you’re saying the VM is on a different class subnet? Its not on any subnet until it gets an IP address and subnet mask from the DHCP server. If both systems are connected to the same switch, then the VM is going to pull an IP address from the DHCP server. DHCP clients use broadcast packets to find DHCP servers on the local network. That means every system on the local network receives the packet, regardless of IP address or subnet configurations on the individual devices.

Comment: @Appleoddity , i did a test and if the virual lan switch is 192.168.70.1/24 and the dhcp server scope is 192.168.80.1/24 then the vm doesnt get dhcp , becouse its looking for dhcp server on this subnet 192.168.70.0/24 , im right ?

Comment: What does “the virual lan switch is 192.168.70.1/24,” mean to you? A switch does not have a virtual lan “scope.” It’s a switch. ALL devices sitting on the same vLAN or network switch can communicate with each other at Layer 2 regardless of their IP addresses and subnets (Layer 3). vLANs work at layer 2, NOT layer 3. What I think you are referring to is that you created a virtual interface on the switch, which has the IP address 192.168.70.1. That means nothing about devices talking to each other. It just means the switch is reachable by devices in the same vLAN via the 192.168.70.1 IP address.

Comment: On a real switch, I would create a VLAN (say the ID is 10). I would then put two devices plugged in to the switch on vLAN 10. I would then create a virtual interface on the switch that is on vLAN 10 with the IP of 192.168.70.1/24. I would then assign static IP addresses to the two connected devices in the 192.168.70.0/24 range. Each device could then talk to each other AND the switch. Or, instead of using static IP addresses one of those devices can be a DHCP server to give out IP addresses to the other device - like you did. However, your DHCP range is outside the 192.168.70.1 network…..

Comment: So, the switch will be unreachable. But the two devices will talk to each other still.

Comment: @Appleoddity maybe this will help to understand what i mean
https://ibb.co/b3rTHpP

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. So it is like I originally explained. The VM gets an IP from the DHCP server even though the DHCP server’s IP address is 192.168.70.1 on a different subnet. Again, that is because DHCP works at layer 2 BEFORE a device ever even has an IP address. Packets traverse a physical network via MAC addresses not IP addresses. Read up on the DHCP protocol. The VM (DHCP Client) has no IP or subnet - it will then ask all devices on the physical network if they can provide one - and your DHCP Server readily does that. Even if different layer 3 subnets are in use.

Comment: Also study up on the 7 layers of the OSI model and the ARP protocol.

Comment: @Appleoddity , first thank you very much for the help , i get what u say but when im doing like this https://ibb.co/cYbJJpz the vm doesnt get dhcp , how so ? if the  Packets traverse a physical network .

Comment: Probably because the first picture shows your DHCP scope as a /16. And your second picture shows it as a /24. And as a /24 192.168.80.x is outside the range 192.168.70.x and maybe Windows DHCP server will not assign IP addresses outside of its own network because this would usually be an invalid setup. I’m very confused by the direction this conversation has gone and I suggest that you [edit] your question and provide the new information and clarify it as to exactly what you are trying to do and what the problem is. It has been very difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: @Appleoddity this answer is what i'v thinking about :) thanks for the help